# Can I create windows phone applications using java

Tags: java, c#, android, visual-studio, windows-phone

I have learnt android application programming. My command is with java.

Some sites provides their sdk for multi platform development, but i am not getting them

Xamarin can develop androids app using c#. Is reverse possible?

Can i develop windows app using java? If yes how?

Comment: Do you want to write a cross-platform app or will your Windows Phone app be a separate thing altogether? If it's separate, just use C# - Microsoft did a brilliant job of ripping-off Java when they created C#. There are differences but I started with C# years ago and it only took me a short time to get comfortable with Java when I started programming for Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.  [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) is an SDK that will allow you to create Android, iOS, RIM, and Windows mobile apps all by using native Java.

[Source](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/09/12/write-windows-8-apps-in-native-java.aspx)

Comment: bro i mentioned in ques that i know about these sites. . is there any native way like installing java extension to visual studio or something like that. . ??
anyways thanks for reply.  i'll try that. .

Answer (score 0):

yes you can develop windows app using java , actually the main point of java is that you can run it on multiple platform (`write-once-run-everywhere`) ,i can't get what you mean with how, you build jar file from your app so you can run it everywhere that has `jdk` or `jre`

and about android , yes you can write it using c# ,i hope this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/663461/Developing-Android-Apps-using-Csharp) will be helpfull.

Comment: There is no way how to install Java JVM on a Windows Phone. Therefore it is not possible to run usual Java programs there.